How to place icon in the row?
I have Row widget that contains a column with colorful containers and the red icon.
Row(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 30,
            width: 100,
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          ),              
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.add_circle,
      color: Colors.red,
      size: 30,
    )
  ],
)

I want the red icon to be located not in the center, but on top (near the first yellow container). crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start not working.  How can it be moved up?

You can wrap yellow Container with another column and putting on  the icon init


By setting crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start on the Row, both the Column and the Icon are aligned at the start (top in this case).
The Column's children (the containers) will stack vertically, while the Icon will be placed beside the column, aligned to the top.

Thus, your provided code will work as expected:
Row(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // Aligns children
children: [
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // Aligns containers to the start
    children: [
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      Container(
        height: 30,
        width: 100,
        color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
const Icon(
  Icons.add_circle,
  color: Colors.red,
  size: 30, // Icon will be aligned at the top next to the yellow container
  ),
 ],


